# Kotlin: Why isn't job.invokeOnCompletion() block running on main thread?

Tags: multithreading, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

In my Android application I have code that should run periodically in its own coroutine and should be cancelable.

for this I have the following functions:

**startJob()**: Initializes the job, sets up `invokeOnCompletion()` and starts the work loop in the respective scope

```
private fun startJob() {
    if (::myJob.isInitialized && myJob.isActive) {
        return
    }
    myJob= Job()
    myJob.invokeOnCompletion {
        it?.message.let {
            var msg = it
            if (msg.isNullOrBlank()) {
                msg = "Job stopped. Reason unknown"
            }
            myJobCompleted(msg)
        }
    }
    CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO + myJob).launch {
        workloop()
    }
}
```

**workloop()**: The main work loop. Do some work in a loop with a set delay in each iteration:

```
private suspend fun workloop() {
    while (true) {
        // doing some stuff here
        delay(setDelayInMilliseconds)
    }
}
```

**myJobCompleted**: do some finalizing. For now simply log a message for testing.

```
private fun myJobCompleted(msg: String) {
    try {
        mainActivityReference.logToGUI(msg)
    }
    catch (e:Exception){
        println("debug: " + e.message)
    }
}
```

Running this and calling `myJob.Cancel()` will throw the following exception in `myJobCompleted()`:

> debug: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.

I'm curious as to why this code isn't running on the main thread, since `startJob()` IS called from the main thread?

Furthermore: is there a option similar to using a [CancellationTokenSource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.cancellationtokensource?view=net-5.0) in `c#`, where the job is not immediately cancelled, but a cancellation request can be checked each iteration of the while loop?
Immediately breaking off the job, regardless of what it is doing (although it will pretty much always be  waiting for the delay on cancellation) doesn't seem like a good idea to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not the contract of `Job.invokeOnCompletion` to run on the same thread where `Job` is created. Moreover, such a contract would be impossible to implement.

You can't expect an arbitrary piece of code to run on an arbitrary thread, just because there was some earlier method invocation on that thread. The ability of the Android main GUI thread to execute code submitted from the outside is special, and involves the existence a top-level event loop.

In the world of coroutines, what controls thread assignment is the *coroutine context*, while clearly you are outside of any context when creating the job. So the way to fix it is to explicitly `launch(Dispatchers.Main)` a coroutine from within `invokeOnCompletion`.

About you question on cancellation, you can use `withContext(NonCancellable)` to surround the part of code you want to protect from cancellation.

Comment: Just one comment: There is no difference between `launch(Dispatchers.Main)` and  `CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main).launch {}`, is there? The whole naming convention in Kotlin is still a bit confusing to me....

Comment: There is a difference, actually: `CoroutineScope(Main).launch` is the same bad practice as `GlobalScope.launch(Main)`. When writing `launch(Main)` I intentionally left out the choice of coroutine scope because this topic is not about that.